# Gulp: npm install gulp --save-dev was expecting to see just a gulp folder inside the node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

Wonder if someone can tell me if im doing something wrong?

1. Downloaded Node from there website
2. Installed Gulp globally (npm install --global gulp)
3. Made a folder and inside ran (npm init) which makes the package.json file
4. Installed gulp to the project (npm install --save-dev gulp)

This then adds gulp as a dependency inside package.json and creates a node_modules folder.

I was expecting to only see a gulp folder inside node_modules folder like so:

```
| node_modules
|-- gulp
```

But for some reason it's adding around 132 extra dependency folders, is this correct, should this happen? I would of thought these should be contained inside the gulp folder itself?

- Im using a Mac, Node v5.2.0, NPM v3.3.12, Gulp v3.9.0

Answer (score 0):

`npm` since v3 puts almost all dependencies to the `node_modules` directly.

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's `node_modules` folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

References:

- https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0